# Not showing the proper results in excel with VBA(excel) -Connected to mysql

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am a beginner with VBA. I managed to run mySQL query in VBA which works but I get the same number in all my excel column results. I am not sure what I should change in my code for distinct results to show. Can anybody help me out?

```
    strSql = "SELECT COUNT(*), destination_id FROM `order`   " & _
     "JOIN user ON user.id = order.destination_id   " & _
     "WHERE payment_status = 'pay'  " & _
     "AND email NOT LIKE '%@thelts.com' " & _
     "AND email NOT LIKE '%trend.com' " & _
     "AND `is_dinstinct` IS NULL; "



    rs.Open strSql, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

    res = rs.GetRows

    rs.Close

    Range("A1", "B6") = res(0, 0)
```

Comment: maybe the ``is_dinstinct`` is causing the error -> should be ``is_distinct``, no? and how about `Range("A1:B6") = res`, dropping the `(0,0)`

Comment: `Range("A1").CopyFromRecordSet rs`

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the help but they didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Two things, it looks like you are missing a GROUP BY destination_id in your sql (although thst may be legal in mysql, im a sql server dude) but I believe your real problem is in the line...

Range("A1", "B6") = res(0, 0)

What you are saying here is put the result at position 0, 0 in each cell of the range.

You could try

Range("a1") = res(0, 0)

Range("b6") = res(0, 1)

Comment: Hey Rich. Thanks for helping out. I did forget GROUP BY destination_id. However, when I change my range to Range("a1") = res(0, 0) Range("b6") = res(0, 1). I get an error message.

Comment: I thought that may happen try 0, 0 and 1, 0 instead. I believe that the getrows function returns the array the opposite way round than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

`CopyFromRecordset`is the method I (& @TimWilliams) use to write a result to a range - You may find it a little more helpful than loading into an array first

An example from the [excel help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb223288%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
For iCols = 0 to rs.Fields.Count - 1
    ws.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
Next
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

placing this method in your code,

```
strSql = "SELECT COUNT(*), destination_id FROM `order`   " & _
"JOIN user ON user.id = order.destination_id   " & _
"WHERE payment_status = 'pay'  " & _
"AND email NOT LIKE '%@thelts.com' " & _
"AND email NOT LIKE '%trend.com' " & _
"AND `is_dinstinct` IS NULL; "

rs.Open strSql, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: Hey Sean. Thanks for the help. But I am a real beginner with vba. Do you think you can give me a quick example with the code I put?

Comment: updated with example. I am assuming rs is defined as `ADODB.Recordset`, or as `Recordset`